# Can I step through VB6 code with VS2013 exclusively?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vb6

I recently inherited an old VB6 project complete with built binaries, source code, project files, etc. but no pdb files. Is there any way I can fire up this VB6 application and step through it using the VS2013 tools? Or do I need to install the VB6 IDE?

Comment: You need VB6 IDE. The two development environments are too different. And to say nothing about the language itself

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't do VB6. It was a totally separate product with its own IDE.

Comment: If I install VB6 IDE now, will it hose up my VS2013 installation?

Comment: I think no, but I suggest to have a separate  virtual machine for this kind of work

Comment: You can install VB6 and .NET Visual Studios without either one affecting the other.

Comment: You have always been able to install VB6 and any number of versions of Visual Studio side by side.

Comment: Still, if possible, I would install it in an XP VM.  It runs better than it does in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly open a VB6 project, as-is, in VS .NET.

But what you had in mind may be a procedure to debug compiled VB6 through Visual Studio; this is possible assuming you could recompile the VB6 modules to include PDB files. Without them I do not think this would function very well, if at all.

> **[Debugging VB6 binaries in Visual Studio .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robgruen/2004/11/09/debugging-vb6-binaries-in-visual-studio-net/)**, by robgruen November 9, 2004
>
> If you are using interop to call into a VB6 ActiveX dll or exe and you
>   need to debug your VB6 project you may find yourself having both
>   VS.NET and the VB6 IDE open.  This can certainly be far from
>   efficient.
>
> Typically you set your VB6 project to “Wait for the Component to be
>   created” and you launch your .NET app and then hit breakpoints within
>   the VB6 component.  Well, there’s an easier way to do this.  You can
>   actually debug your VB6 component within VS.NET.  Here’s what you need
>   to do:
>
> 1. Build your VB6 project with symbols.
>
>    In VB6 open up your vbp file and goto “Project->Properties.”  Select
>      the “compile” tab and check “Compile to Native Code.”  Then select the
>      “No Optimization” radio button and check “Create Symbolic Debug Info.”
>
>    This will generate a .PDB (Program Database) file along with your
>      .EXE.  This file contains the debugging information so the VS.NET
>      debugger can line up source and hit breakpoints, etc.  (Make sure you
>      have binary compatibility on your VB6 dll set or you’ll have to drop
>      and re-add your reference to the VB6 component in VS.NET.)
> 2. Open your .NET project in VS.NET.
> 3. Go to the project properties and select the “Configuration Properties->Debugging” property page and enable unmanaged debugging.
>
>    For VB.NET projects this option is “Unmanaged code debugging” and for
>      C# is “enable unmanaged debugging” [or "enable native code debugging"].
> 4. Select the property page for the solution.
> 5. Add to the “Debug Source Files” an entry that points to the path where the source code is for the VB6 component.
> 6. Add to the “Debug Symbols Files” an entry that points to the folder where the .PDB file is that was generated in step 1.
>
> You should now be able to open your .bas, .cls, .frm, etc. files in
>   VS.NET and you can put breakpoints in the file.  Once you debug the
>   debugger will stop on those lines of code.

Comment: This other question notes some problems with getting this to actually work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194108/c-sharp-project-wont-load-debugging-symbols-from-vb6-dll

Answer (score -1):

If you can get a copy of VB.NET 2003, 2005 or 2008, that is the version of VB.NET that has the ability to convert a VB6 project, into a VB.NET project.   Later VB.NET versions wont open/operate on a VB6 Project.

So, your options are VB 6, or, VB 2003, 2005 or 2008 (or, a modern copy of VB.Net... and a lot manual effort to convert the code. I hope it's not a big application. )

Comment: FYI, that is not the only version of Visual Studio .NET that had the conversion tool. They had the tool all the way until 2010 VS.NET; that version and subsequent versions no longer contained the tool

Comment: To echo Ghost's comment, versions of VB.NET up to 2008 can upgrade VB6 projects; 2010 and later cannot.

Comment: Thank you Ghost.   I stand corrected, and will go back and do my homework on that point.