# C# project won't load debugging symbols from VB6 DLL

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, pdb-files

I have a VB6 DLL which I have compiled with debugging symbols turned ON. A PDB file is created alongside the DLL.

However in the C# project which references this DLL, it is refusing to load the PDB file.

In the VS modules window it states

> "Binary was not built with debug information"

for this DLL. This is incorrect...

If I right click in the Modules window and select "Load Symbols", and then manually select the PDB file, I get the error

> "A matching symbol file was not found in this folder."

[image]

which also seems to be inaccurate.

I must be doing *something* wrong - any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try VS2015 (5 more to go). . .

Comment: Hi @wqw; I am using VS2015, actually. I'm not sure what I've done wrong!

Comment: Try fiddling with `Tools->Options->Debugging` -- here is a [screenshot of my options](https://dl.unicontsoft.com/upload/pix/ss_vs2015_options_debugging.png) that work for me. Probably somthing to do with `Enable Native Compatibility Mode`, it was an option that is missing in VS2017 now and old PDBs are a problem there.